# How Do I Remove The Notification From The Screen After Being Clicked On

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, ios11

For a few months, I have been working on an app which uses local UNNotifications to achieve the grand goal. I coded this app using Swift 4, therefore aiming it towards distribution on the iOS App Store. As I was testing my app out, I noticed that after I clicked on one of the notification actions (which was not "cancel"), or if I just tapped on the notification in general, the app would open up (which is intended), but the notification would remain on the screen. Is there any possible way to remove the notification from the screen after already tapping on one of the actions programmatically? Below is the code where I schedule the notification:

```
   let action1 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "go", title: "Go", options: [.foreground])
        let action2 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "cancel", title: "Cancel", options: [.destructive])

        let actionsCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "actions.category", actions: [action1, action2], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([actionsCategory])


        //Queue the notification alert
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = "Interesting day notification!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.setValue(true, forKey: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")
        content.categoryIdentifier = "actions.category"
       // if (pinNumber.text) != nil{
      //  }

        content.userInfo = ["Name": namePerson.text ?? "", "Pin": Int(pinNumber.text ?? "") != nil ? pinNumber.text! : ""]

        //trigger
        let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute], from: datePicker.date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

        //scheduling
        let identifier = id // set same id as task
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }else{
                print("saved alert")
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and describe the device configuration (simulator/phone iOS version...)? Also try restarting.

Comment: I know that it has nothing to do with the simulator or iOS version because it has been tested on numerous different iOS devices. This is something that I am trying to figure out programmatically

Comment: The user can choose if notifications are temporary or permanent in Settings.

Comment: @Gruntcakes But on all of the testing devices, the notification settings are set as temporary, which means that that does not change anything in this exact case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in your code that would cause that behavior. This sounds to me like either an iOS bug, or there is something weird about the notification permissions/settings of the particular device (or simulator) for your app. Go into the notifications sections of the Settings app and see what the settings are for your app.

Comment: yes, it just uses local UNNotifications presented by the OS.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ugh. This is a big problem with StackOverflow. Nobody can ask for clarification unless they're already have tons of reputation, but it's impossible to answer enough questions to have good reputation unless you can ask for clarification. Thanks for the downvote :(